# Add image after first image element jquery

Tags: jquery, image, insert, append, appendto

I'm trying to add images dynamically in a div element. So I have a block like that

```
<div id="gallery" >
    <img src="images/slide1.jpg" alt="Slide 1 />
    <img src="images/slide2.jpg" alt="Slide 2 />
    <img src="images/slide3.jpg" alt="Slide 3 />
    <img src="images/slide4.jpg" alt="Slide 4 />
</div>
```

The idea is to insert image dynamically after the first image so my new image goes after the first image. I tried appendTo, append , after, insertAfter .

Do you have any ideas ?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> You have some malformed HTML there- I'm going to assume it was a mistake when copying the code...

Perhaps this will help -

```
$('<img src="foo.jpg" />').insertAfter("#gallery > img:first");
```

If you want to use the `insertAfter()` function, you have to be sure that you have selected the correct element.  In this case it is

- the first `img` tag -  `:first`
- in the first level of children  `>`
- in the element with an id of `gallery`. - `$("#gallery")`

Comment: @roko - caught it 1sec before me!  At least give me the 5min grace edit time ;) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks you, my problem is solved by an other way. Problem of conception so I resolved it by myself but your answer really really helped ! Thanks you so much !

Comment: @Simon it would be really nice to know (and for future generations also:) **How did you do it?** And still, I'd accept this answer...

Answer (score 0):

There is the answer to my problem, I resolved it by using this line :

```
$image.insertBefore("#container > img:last");
```

I remember that I add my pictures by the end and no the beginning of the container element.

Thanks again.